# Altering Oracle sequence using result of expression

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i, ora-01722

I have two variables

```
MAX_TABLE_ID INTEGER;
NEXT_TABLE_ID INTEGER;
```

I'm reading values into these and then trying to alter a sequence based on them

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE NEXT_VALIDATED_TABLE_ID INCREMENT BY [MAX_TABLE_ID-NEXT_TABLE_ID]';
```

Bit I'm getting an "invalid number" error or a SQL command not ended error.

This even happens if I try hardcoded numbers

```
ALTER SEQUENCE NEXT_VALIDATED_TABLE_ID INCREMENT BY 100-1; or

ALTER SEQUENCE NEXT_VALIDATED_TABLE_ID INCREMENT BY [100-1];
```

Am i missing something obvious here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try doing the calculation outside the literal, eg

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE NEXT_VALIDATED_TABLE_ID INCREMENT BY ' || MAX_TABLE_ID-NEXT_TABLE_ID;
```